# No instance of constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create my own Vector2D class, similar to that of XNA's, to store coordinates in. Following the example of constructors found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Class/Constructoranddestructorinsideastruct.htm), I created the code below. However, I get an error saying that there is no instance of constructor "Vector2D::Vector2D" that matches the argument list. I don't see how that can be... What seems to be my problem?

```
struct Vector2D {
    Vector2D(int *varX, int *varY);
    ~Vector2D();
    private: int *X, *Y;
};

Vector2D::Vector2D(int *varX, int *varY) {
    X = varX;
    Y = varY;
}

Vector2D::~Vector2D() {
    free(X);
    free(Y);

}
```

Comment: Could you show the exact error? :)

Comment: Why use pointers? Why `free` them in the destructor if you're not 100% sure they were allocated with `malloc`?

Comment: More to the point, could you show the line that produced error?

Comment: Why pointers? Why `free`? Is the class declaration available before you define the member bodies? Use initialiser list in that ctor.

Comment: Post the line that causes the error.

Comment: BTW, this class will misbehave when copied, see [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @Cat I think the real problem is an obvious misunderstanding of C++ OO design. A good book would be useful.

Comment: **Do not learn C++ from the internet.** Case in point, that site is terrible. You must get [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), nothing online will substitute.

Comment: Oh, there's a site, I haven't noticed that. Tip for future: if you *think* you need pointers, then you probably don't.

Comment: Lots of upvoted comments here.

Comment: It's upboats all the way down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely trying to create your `Vector2D` class like this:

```
Vector2D vector(1, 2);
```

You can't do that using pointers to `int` like you've done in your Vector2D constructor definition because those values are not pointers, they are integer constants.  Change to simple `int` objects like this:

```
struct Vector2D 
{
    Vector2D(int varX, int varY): X(varX), Y(varY) {}  //initialization list
    //~Vector2D();  delete the destructor since it's not needed anymore

    int X, Y;
};
```

There's also no need for the destructor since your data objects are not pointers, and therefore there is no extra cleanup of allocated memory on the heap needed at the object's destruction. I've just commented it out so you can see it's not needed anymore.

Finally, you probably *don't* want your data-members as `private` if you're using a struct ... you can do it, but you'll then have to add some functions to access those data memebers (i.e., if you declare them `private` then you can't do things like `vector.x = 5;`).  Typically you'd use a `class` if you want to default to `private` access, as `struct` defaults to `public` access.

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely a bad example I choose to base things off of. Thanks for the help, I understand better now. I still have much to learn on pointers. It's still throwing some errors though. It's saying Vector2D is an undeclared identifier. There are some other errors too, but I know they are because of the above one. I don't understand why it wouldn't be an identifier after what we just did.

Comment: Are you creating a vector object using syntax like `Vector2D vector(1,2);`?  Also are you trying to define `Vector2D` inside a header file, or inside a code-module (i.e., a .cpp file)?

Comment: You can see a working example of your vector struct in-use here http://ideone.com/wrg9U

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use it with syntax like that, no I'm not trying to define it inside a header file, yes I am trying to define it inside a .cpp file. I have another struct in this .cpp file working fine. Should I move this one?

Comment: You might have accidentally forgotten a semi-colon, bracket, etc. on another struct/class declaration that is messing up the declaration of your `Vector2D` struct.  So even though the syntax for Vector2D struct is fine, the C++ parser can't parse it correctly into a proper identifier.  It's thinking the structure is part of something else.

Comment: I'm doing that code snippet verbatim! My solution file is one that my prof gave out, and it's using the irrlicht engine. Unfortunately, we can only edit the one cpp file. I'm not even sure we are allowed to add files to the project. We don't have to create a vector struct, but it's so much easier to work with coordinates like that =P

Comment: WOW. NEVER MIND. I had the struct declared at the end... moved it to the top and it worked. Lesson learned... wow. I'm retarded. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you chose a bad example to base this on.  The example is a string class, so it takes pointers, allocates and frees storage etc.  Strings are variable length, so they need to do stuff like that.

I'm guessing the error came from something like

```
Vector2D v(3, 5);
```

The problem is your constructor takes `int*` arguments, and you are calling it with `int` arguments.  You should not be using pointers here.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for the help. It was stupid to try and use pointers without really knowing what they do fully. C++ isn't really something you can hack together real quick with if you're new, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in definition, but in how you use the class.
For example, code like this:

```
int main(){
    Vector2D v2D_none;
}
```

Will yield the error you're talking about, because there's no default (no parameters) constructor. Calling `Vector2D v2D(1,2)` will also fail because of the type mismatch.

Also, having `free` in the destructor is a bad choice, as was pointed out in comments. Why do you use pointers anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the problem is that you are passing int's instead of pointers to int.

If you want to keep the parameters as pointers to integer, you have to pass your parameters as pointers, or create a new int while passing the parameter this way:

```
Vector2D v(new int(4), new int(8));
```

As you can see, I pass as parameters the integers 4 and 8.

Be aware of destroying the variables using `delete` instead of `free`. Or you can also adapt the problem using `malloc/free`.

Here you do need a destructor because you are allocating space on-demand while passing the parameters.

Comment: No, never mix `malloc`/`free` and `new`/`delete`/`delete[]`. It will break, crash and burn; especially for non-POD types.

Comment: Yeah, `free()` will just destroy the memory allocated to the pointer, but will not call the non-POD object's destructor, which will be very bad news ...

Comment: @Jason: Or it might be a completely different allocator, and it ends up corrupting the heap or crashing the program.